# Values not passed from Textbox to code

Tags: c#, textbox

my code :

## region check what Login button do

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.txtUserName.Text == "" || this.txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Credentials are missing...", clsVariables._strProjectName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            string _strQuery = "SELECT AtNumConstructorID, TxtConstructorName AS Fullname, tblConstructorDetails.txtUserName FROM tblConstructorDetails WHERE txtUserName = '" + this.txtUserName.Text + "' AND TxtPassword LIKE '" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ";
            if (clsFunctions.recordExist(_strQuery, "tblConstructorDetails") == true)
            {
                clsVariables._sTimeLogin = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();//recording the time of login in the CES
                long totalRow = 0;
                //Set the Data Adapter
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(_strQuery, clsConnections._olbedbCN);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // creating a dataset to enter the values in the dataadapter
                da.Fill(ds, "tblConstructorDetails");
                totalRow = ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows.Count - 1;
                clsVariables._sContId = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0));
                clsVariables._sConstructor = ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
                clsVariables._sUserID = ds.Tables["tblConstructorDetails"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
                clsUserLogs.RecordLogin(clsVariables._sTimeLogin, clsVariables._sContId);
                clsApplication._boolAPP_CONNECTED = true;
                this.Close();

            }
            #region trash code 2
            /*string _strUsername = this.txtUserName.Text.Trim();
            string _strPassword = txtPassword.Text;
            string _strSQL = "select * from tblConstructorDetails where Upper(TxtUserName) = '" +  _strUsername.ToUpper() +"' and TxtPassword = '" + _strPassword +  "'";
            if ()
            {

            } */
            #endregion

            else
            {
                clsVariables._intAttempt--;
                if (clsVariables._intAttempt > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed. Please try again. Only " + Convert.ToString(clsVariables._intAttempt) + " attempts remaining...", "Login Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Exiting the system", clsVariables._strProjectName, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

code for recordExist :

```
    #region Filters the records if exists in the table
    //Filter if Recort is Exist in the Table.
    public static bool recordExist(string _sSQL, string _sTable)
    {
        long totalRow = 0;
        //Set the Data Adapter
        OleDbDataAdapter _oledbAdDa = new OleDbDataAdapter(_sSQL, _olbedbCN);
        DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
        _oledbAdDa.Fill(_ds, _sTable);
        totalRow = Convert.ToInt32(_ds.Tables[_sTable].Rows.Count);
        if (totalRow > 0) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
    #endregion
```

The problem I am facing is that, when I try to enter values in the corresponding textbox, that values are not been passed to the query for checking if the login is available or not....

Please check the same and provide me the possible solution and reason for why this thing is happening....

Thanx in advance....

Comment: why not remove all the irrelevant code. The problem is that the if statement at the top is true even when text is in the text boxes right? - that will also stop anyone from telling you not to build sql strings like this because someone will come along and do seomthing nasty.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to change the string comparison operator in your sql from

=

to

LIKE

I get the feeling that you have miss asked your question and really the problem is the sql returning no data.

```
string _strQuery = "SELECT AtNumConstructorID, TxtConstructorName AS Fullname, tblConstructorDetails.txtUserName FROM tblConstructorDetails WHERE txtUserName LIKE '" 
+ this.txtUserName.Text + "' AND TxtPassword LIKE '" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ";
```

the change is right at the ernd of the first line.

http://xkcd.com/327/